# Magento error: Mage registry key "controller" already exists

Tags: php, security, magento, restore

I have this site that runs Magento. The index.php file outputs a list of emails and encrypted stuff that seems to be a passwords.
I have marked out with red sensible information.

[image]

-All URLs give internal server error 500

-I have done the step by step verification recommended by a lot of sites, like this one:[https://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/][2] but it has not solved the issue at all.

The error message I found at /var/report was the following: I cant really understand what it means.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:45:
"Mage registry key "controller" already exists"
;i:1;s:631:"
#0 /home/filomena/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/filomena/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(747): Mage::register('controller', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front))
#2 /home/filomena/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1094): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initFrontController()
#3 /home/filomena/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->getFrontController()
#4 /home/filomena/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#5 /home/filomena/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#6 {main}"
;s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

- I cant open the admin panel ,also I get internal server error 500
- I wonder if there is a guide to recover from this kind of issues.
- Have I been hacked?

Comment: Check in some of the custom modules (community or local) if there is this call: Mage::register('controller'...); since the error in your log means that you are trying to register a variable called 'controller' but that's already used for the main front controller. In order to fix it, add third parameter to the call of register method: Mage::register('controller', $yourValue, true); Although not sure why that stuff prints out.

Comment: Hi @zokibtmkdl, I dont know how to do this, should I search for the call in the files? I have tried to move the foldes of the modules from both folders local and community to a temporary folder outside of /app/ , but the problem still is reported.
I would appreciate if you could point me out ho m to do anything. I dont understand very well how Mage works, I have always us WP/Woo commerce. Really appreciate your help to make me understand better this software :)

Comment: According to the error, it means somewhere in app/code/local or app/code/community there is a call for Mage::register('controller', $someValue); but if that's not the case, you can also check if Compilation is being enabled. System -> Tools -> Compilation in the admin. Disable it and try if that fixes your error.

Comment: I cannot access the admin, when I try to enter I get a internal server error. Did you saw the image I posted? Why is index.php file showing a list of emails and user data? Was the site hacked? Thanks, i will try this that you suggest today.

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush whole Magento cache. If you use Redis, connect to server via SSH, then:
redis-cli
flushall 
exit

If no, remove all files and directories from: magento_root_dir/var/cache

Comment: thanks. the site was competely hacked. had to reinstall magento core files.